# Can GPO prevent WSUS post install tasks?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, wsus

Just rebuilt my WSUS Server 2012 R2 x64 from a VLSC disc. Added drivers and then joined the server to the domain. I then tried to install WSUS. I was able to add the feature. Then during post install I get the following error:

```
2017-09-08 14:25:20  CreateDefaultSubscription failed. Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Client found response content type of 'text/html; charset=utf-8', but expected 'text/xml'.
CS0016: Complier error: C:\Windows\Microsoft .NET\Framework64\Temporary ASP.NET Files\apiremoting30\asdv832.dll -- 503 Access denied
```

Is there something in my GPO that is preventing an account from accessing this directory? This directory has not been specified anywhere in my GPOs but it immediately failed when on my domain. When the server is off the network it installs WSUS without a problem. How can I check?

Comment: You should also be sure to tell people you are seeking help in multiple places, it is rude to send people on the run around in multiple forums: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/f17f01da-c19d-438f-9c7e-47f80364d509/wsus-will-not-install-after-joining-domain-createdefaultsubscriptionfailed?forum=winserverwsus

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take an off the wall guess here based on some research I did. I wonder if this is the first and only time you tried installing WSUS on this server?

Once the components in IIS have been built, you may have conflicts if you have tried to reinstall WSUS multiple times or you used a default installation of IIS. Either way, this is what I would try.

First, try to remove the static and dynamic compression module on IIS and reinstall WSUS.

- On the taskbar, click **Server Manager**.
- In **Server Manager**, click the **Manage** menu, and then click **Remove Roles and Features.**
- In the **Remove Roles and Features** wizard, click **Next**. Select the destination server and click **Next**.
- On the **Server Roles** page, un-select **Windows Server Update Services** and expand **Web Server (IIS)**, expand **Web Server**, expand **Performance**, and then un-select **Static Content Compression** and/or **Dynamic Content Compression**. Click **Next**.
- On the **Remove features** page, click **Next**.
- On the **Confirm removal selections** page, click **Remove**.
- On the **Results page**, click **Close**.

Now, re-add the **WSUS** role and see if it will complete. Do not allow it to re-add the *static* or *dynamic* compression modules.

If it still fails, try to completely remove the **Web Server (IIS)** and **WSUS roles**, delete the `C:\Inetpub` folder and re-add the **WSUS** role allowing it to add the additional components necessary for the **Web Server (IIS)** role automatically.